# Сокращение ссылок Goo.gl API

Tags: python, api

Нужно сокращать ссылки через сервис goo.gl
с помощью API

свой ключ API получил.
установил
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client

как делать в программном коде не знаю.
какой модуль импортировать?
какие команды API?
например ссылка www.google.com

Comment: Документацию почитать не? https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started

Comment: документация для меня не понятна, так как на английском. мне бы простой пример.

Comment: Никто за вас тут ничего делать не будет. Ищите исполнителя за деньги на соответствующих ресурсах.

Comment: @ilyaplot: вы неправильно себе представляете цели и задачи сайта. [Работа за автора](https://goo.gl/mr8PVb)

Comment: @jfs Почему же тогда 5 человек оценили мой комментарий? Возможно, вы неправильно представляете цели и задачи сайта? Здесь помогают людям разобраться в собственном коде, а не пишут бесплатно код за него.

Comment: @ilyaplot потому что у комментариев нет кнопки минус, чтобы вы реальный счёт увидели (к примеру -25). Комментарии не место для мета-обсуждений. Если вы считаете что такие вопросы должны быть закрыты, то [оставьте там свой ответ](https://goo.gl/mr8PVb) и мы посмотрим как люди проголосуют.

Comment: @ilyaplot: вот [ответ на Мете, который кратко и без мата объясняет в чём у вас заблуждение](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3892/23044)

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov *"невозможно дать лаконичный ответ"* это неверно, посмотрите на [принятый ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/613831/23044)—вполне лаконичный.

Comment: К сожалению, вопрос всё равно плохо сформулирован, а ответ отвечает на "Как сократить ссылку из кода на Python?", а не те вопросы, что приведены в данном сообщении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы создать короткую goo.gl ссылку `short_url` из длинной ссылки `long_url`, используя ключ `api_key` от Гугла, можно [http POST запрос выполнить](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#shorten):

```
import requests  # $ pip install requests

api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'
r = requests.post("{api_url}?key={api_key}".format(**vars()), json={'longUrl': long_url})
short_url = r.json()['id']
```

Полный пример [`goo_gl.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/5784d427a0c502e02205260dd311cebd#file-goo_gl-py).